# Angular Meteor app works in localhost but fails when deployed to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

An Angular Meteor app using `angular-with-blaze` package works well on `localhost` but when deployed to a server using `mup` and `mupx`, the site loads partially and throw the following error in the browser JS console:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

Thinking this is due to minification of the JS files, I tried the following setting for `mupx` but it did not help.

```
"buildOptions": {
  // build with the debug mode on
  "debug": true
}
```

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Looks like it might be an Angular minification problem. add `strict-di` (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) so that you can debug this change also on develop and see if that problem appears.  also, you can turn your Angular JS files into .ng.js to get ng-annotate out of the box.

Comment: @Urigo Does standard-minifiers package support angular-with-blaze ? When I try to deploy to modulus or galaxy I get minification errors ? However if i remove the standard-minifiers package it seems to deploy fine .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gulp task 'gulp-ng-annotate' if you are using gulp or grunt-ng-annotate respectively. It will add required annotations to dependencies in your modules according to angular [Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).